# How do I make this sprite behave how I want?

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following html where my div middle contain has a background image. This is a full width image that I want to take up the whole screen and stay centered on width collapse for responsive design. I also have a header and a footer that have similar full length images that behave the same, but not I am only showing code for the middle image here:

```
   <div id="contain">
     <div id="middle_contain">
       <div class="lawyer_select">
            <div class="lawyer_hold">
                <img src="images/example.jpg" width="252" height="286" alt="stuff" /></div>
            <div class="lawyer_hold">
                <img src="images/example.jpg" width="252" height="286" alt="things" />
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Which has the following CSS:

```
#middle_contain{
      background-image:url(../images/layout/main-example.jpg);
      background-position:center;
      background-size:cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
.lawyer_hold{
    height:312px;
    width:480px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.lawyer_hold:nth-child(2){
    float:right;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Now, the situation I am running into is rather than loading the middle contain image plus a header and footer image, I want to combine them into a sprite. I am having trouble getting the code right for that though so my images stay centered etc upon collapse. I have tried the following css, which positions the image correctly on my largest screen resolution, but now when I collapse everything else breaks down. How do I properly maintain covering the background and keeping it centered while using a sprite? Is this possible or should I stick with three individual images?

```
#middle_contain{
    background-image:url(../images/layout/main-example.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-position:0px -167px;
    background-size:cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to have background image sprites dynamically change in size with just CSS (at least as far as I've been able to figure). If you want to use sprites, you should use JavaScript, but there's no guarantee that mobile devices will support Javascript, so it's kind of a moot point.

The reason you can't resize strictly with CSS is because the image will not maintain proportions; the width of the HTML element will change, but the height will not. If there is any way for the element to maintain these proportions using strictly CSS I would love to know and would whip-up some example code, but as of this moment I don't believe it's possible.

It's definitely best to stick to using 3 separate images in this case. You can, however, sprite images that won't resize.